# Using saveWorkbook in R - How do I add a password?

Tags: r, passwords, xlsx

I sometimes create Excel spreadsheets in R using the `xlsx` package (Version 0.6.1), and I save these with the `saveWorkbook` function.  I am trying to password-protect the Excel file by adding a `password` variable into the save statement as shown in the [package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf).  This attempt leads me to the following error:

```
#The object WB is a workbook created with the xlsx pacakage

> saveWorkbook(WB, "MyFile.xlsx", password = "PASS");
Error in .jnew("org/apache/poi/poifs/crypt/EncryptionInfo", encMode) : 
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
```

I have no idea what this error means.  Can anyone tell me what is wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: You might have an older version of the `xlsx` package. Try reinstalling the `xlsx` package which have the new `password` argument.

Comment: I have Version 0.6.1.  Is that recent enough?

Comment: After doing some searching, it could be due to your `rJava` package. You may want to try reinstalling your `rJava` package. Another reason could be that you might be using the wrong java version (e.g. 32-bit Java with 64-bit R).

Comment: I crossposted this [on github](https://github.com/dragua/xlsx/issues/107), since I got the same issue and don't know what to do about it.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the method is missing in the `xlsxjars` companion. As as workaround, to set a password on Excel workbooks in R, you can use the `RDCOMClient` package e.g. like this:

```
# devtools::install_github("omegahat/RDCOMClient")
set_excel_psw <- function(filename, password = rstudioapi::askForPassword()) {
  require(RDCOMClient)
  filename <- normalizePath(path.expand(filename))
  Application <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
  wkb <- Application$Workbooks()$Open(filename) 
  wkb[['Password']] <- password
  wkb$Save()
  Application$Quit()
  Application <- NULL    
  invisible(gc())
}

xlsx::write.xlsx(iris, tf<-tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx"))
set_excel_psw(filename = tf, password = "foo")
shell.exec(tf)
```

The *Password* property is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.password).